# Why text goes out of the box while using D3 Word Cloud example by Jason Davies?

Tags: d3.js, word-cloud

I am using [D3 Word Cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) for one of my project. In the example it is defined as width and height as 300 * 300. But when I run it sometimes only half of the text shows up in the box. [image: See this Exmple.]

In this example, It is the word "Random" on the left. Only "om" has been displayed.

Can anyone help me how to display the output in a particular region?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post an example of where this occurs please?

Comment: Here is the example. http://egitraining.esc.rl.ac.uk/images/4.jpg

Comment: Could you post the code and data for that example as well please so that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have already given the link in the example. Please check out the screenshot.

Comment: What is the *data* you're using?

Comment: Hi, I am using d3.js and d3.layout.cloud.js file from here. https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud
and using the simple.html code in block content which I showed in the screenshot.

Comment: What is the text that you are drawing the word cloud from?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I didn't get you earlier. Yeah about the text, if you checkout the screenshot, below the first arrow, There is a function called d3.layout.cloud().size().words*["This", "is", "some", "random", "text"].....................
The data is passed from this method.

Comment: Hmm, can't reproduce this with the cloud generator on the website. Maybe it's because of the `g` element you're appending and translating?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I got it working by changing the <<<translate(150, 150)>>> to <<<translate(300, 150)>>>. But I didn't understand how does it work. When we have already defined width and height, what is the use of translate and "g"? Thanks anyways :)

Comment: I think this repositions the coordinate system to the center of the SVG and all the word coordinates are computed from that. So in your case, it should be `translate(400,150)`.

Comment: Oh Ok, got it. Thanks. I tried to change the values and by your this comment, I understood.

Comment: Great, I'll post this as an answer for reference.

Comment: Great. Do you know how do I get the words rotate in all direction, not only in 90 degree. Something like this in his example, https://github-camo.global.ssl.fastly.net/46d82c30560862777d6eef9d32c6d7f79a4dd934/687474703a2f2f7777772e6a61736f6e6461766965732e636f6d2f776f7264636c6f75642f616d617a696e672e706e67
I know I have to change something in d3.layout.cloud().rotate(function). What value should I replace 90 with?

Comment: You can adjust this in the interactive demo, which will also give you the code to do it.

Comment: which demo are you talking about?

Comment: [This one](http://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44958/discussion-between-user2798227-and-lars-kotthoff)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinates of the words in the cloud are computed assuming that the center of the cloud is at (0,0). This is not the case with SVGs, so there's a `g` element below the top-level SVG that has the appropriate coordinate system translation applied. When changing the size of the word cloud, you need to change this as well.

In your case, the size of the word cloud is 800x300, so the translation should be (400,150):

```
.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(400,150)")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the translate should be half of your width and height. Eg if w=300 h=300 then translate should be translate(150,150). Hope it works.